# configure launch.json file everytime when working with new c++ file in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am working with c++ in vscode. I have to configure launch.json file everytime I create and work with a new cpp file. Otherwise, it executes the previous file which I worked on.

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/nxtPrime.cpp.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "echo"
    }
]
```

}

Is there any simple way so that I need not edit launch.json file to give the name of new cpp file every time??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should show your launch.json.  Are you using or aware of ${file} to refer to the current file?  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

Comment: Yeah I know that I can refer to the current file with that command. But I have to do it when I am creating a new file. That means I have to change the that command everytime in launch.json file. It is very redundant and irrritating. That's why I am looking for a solution where I don't need to change file name over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS Code writing C# programs who are kind of relatable to C++

I also chose the Framework "net5.0" and below, nothing of .NET Core even if that name appears in the config.

When you create a new project two files are created on the folder .vscode the launch.json and task.json, the first one is for you, just tweak it a little in the path.

For launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFileDirname}/bin/Debug/net5.0/${relativeFileDirname}.dll",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFileDirname}",
      "console": "internalConsole",
      "stopAtEntry": false
    },
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Attach",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "attach"
    }
  ]
}
```

For the task.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "build",
        "${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFileDirname}/${relativeFileDirname}.csproj",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    },
    {
      "label": "publish",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "publish",
        "${workspaceFolder}/${workspaceFolderBasename}/${workspaceFolderBasename}.csproj",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    },
    {
      "label": "watch",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "watch",
        "run",
        "--project",
        "${workspaceFolder}/${workspaceFolderBasename}/${workspaceFolderBasename}.csproj"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tested it using the **variable references** from the page up to date 2022-04-06 that @Mark recommended above: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference